# NSExtensionActivationRule & iOS App extension: how to activate the extension in iTunes

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone

I want to make an extension for my iOS 8 app (preferably an action extension, but a share extension would do the job as well).
And I want this extension to be accessible from iTunes so my users could send an iTunes link to my app.
But I just can't figure out how to make this extension available from iTunes (and only from iTunes by the way).
I have tried NSExtensionActivationRule.NSExtensionActivationSupportsWebURLWithMaxCount, but it only activated my extension from Safari, not from iTunes.
I wonder if there could be a way to do it with a predicate, but I can't figure out how to build a predicate that can detect an iTunes "element/link" (for lack of a better term).
Does someone have a solution for that ?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

NSExtensionItem from AppStore/iTunes Store apps actually contain three types of attachment which are Image, Text and URL.

You can specify your **NSExtensionActivationRule** to ***TRUEPREDICATE*** first in development which allow all kinds of attachment.

The attachment structure of an AppStore/iTunes Store app extension request can be logged as image:
[image]

As a result, you have to include following keys in **NSExtensionActivationRule** of your extension's info.plist file:

1. NSExtensionActivationSupportsImageWithMaxCount
2. NSExtensionActivationSupportsText
3. NSExtensionActivationSupportsWebURLWithMaxCount

**Update:**

If you want to restrict the probably point showing your extension (which only work for iTunes Store), you could use "predicate statement" for more complex filter.

Please refer to the Apple doc below:
https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/General/Conceptual/ExtensibilityPG/ExtensionScenarios.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014214-CH21-SW8

For example:

I want to make my extension only shows if the extension attachments meet the condition: one image, one plain text and one url, which confirms to the condition as image above. I use following prediction:

```
SUBQUERY (
    extensionItems,
    $extensionItem,
    SUBQUERY (
        $extensionItem.attachments,
        $attachment,
        ANY $attachment.registeredTypeIdentifiers UTI-CONFORMS-TO "public.image"
    ).@count == 1
).@count == 1
&&
SUBQUERY (
    extensionItems,
    $extensionItem,
    SUBQUERY (
        $extensionItem.attachments,
        $attachment,
        ANY $attachment.registeredTypeIdentifiers UTI-CONFORMS-TO "public.url"
    ).@count == 1
).@count == 1
&&
SUBQUERY (
    extensionItems,
    $extensionItem,
    SUBQUERY (
        $extensionItem.attachments,
        $attachment,
        ANY $attachment.registeredTypeIdentifiers UTI-CONFORMS-TO "public.plain-text"
    ).@count == 1
).@count == 1
```

I didn't try to filter inside the attachment (only url contains "itunes.apple.com"), but I think you may use the prediction to restrict the point extension showing in action sheet and have more checking before taking action inside your view controller (not a perfect solution, but should work if there's no better way to check attachment content.)

Cheers!

Comment: Thanks a lot, but how could I restrict the extension strictly to itunes content : URLs that start with "itunes.apple.com" and only those URLs? I cannot figure out a predicate that I could use for NSExtensionActivationRule, that would do the job.

Comment: Yep, works like a charm for iTunes and the action does not seem to appear in other contexts after a few tests. Thanks a lot.

Comment: In which file the subqueries go?

Comment: @pomo in info.plist for extension target

Comment: @Frank how did you get it to only appear for iTunes?

Comment: @JordanH Only difference with what is in Charlie's answer is that I have the following keys in the pList of my extension in the NSExtension group<br/>      
   <key>NSExtensionPointIdentifier</key>
  <string>com.apple.services</string>
    <key>NSExtensionPrincipalClass</key>
  <string>$(PRODUCT_MODULE_NAME).ActionRequestHandler</string>

Comment: Ok, so it seems it would show up for any app sharing an image, url, and text. But that’s probably not real common. I was just curious if you found a way to look specifically for itunes.apple.com URLs in the activation rule.